# Python Indentation in Graphserver's code

Tags: python, indentation

I'm reading code from [GraphServer](http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver/).
And there is this function that has weird indentation (5th line counting from the bottom and the 1st line counting from bottom):

[image]

That fifth to bottom line has a tab character and I have my vim set up to show an indentation of 4. The bottom yield line has a tab plus four spaces. All other lines are all headed by spaces.

I thought code like this would create inconsistency and would be a problem in Python. But the code seems to run fine (I don't know if run correctly, it probably does.). Does python just say ok one tab equals 8 spaces and interpret it as so? I have Python 2.6 running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Python considers a tab to be (up to) 8 spaces, i.e., that there's a tab stop every 8 characters. So that oddly-indented `yield` line actually lines up with the other lines around it in Python-vision.

Such are the perils of working with mixed tabs and spaces. Invoke Python with the `-tt` command-line option to have it throw an error on these kinds of files.

Comment: Not exactly: [the docs say](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=tab%20space#indentation) that when processing a line, "First, tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix)."

Comment: You are technically correct... the best kind of correct! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix tabs and spaces! This is the gemeral rule...